# Java boolean primitive

Tags: java, boolean

Can I do this in java?

```
private static boolean isRight(){
   return new Random.nextBolean();
}

boolean test = true;
test = test && isRight()
```

My question is can I use a boolean to update the same boolean like I would if it were an int or double? Is this a good programming practice or there's a better way

Comment: yes since the whole statement gets eveluated as a boolean expression. Otherwise you could try it out yourself.

Comment: Yes; Java does not have special rules that prevent booleans from working like any other variable.

Comment: The problem here is if `Random` returns `false` then all the values of test, after that, will be false !!

Comment: You can also write `test &= isRight()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes of course you can. `boolean` works in the same way as any other primitive type in Java.

Note however that this is an abuse of `Random`: you should not reinitialise the generator every time you want to draw from it. You could keep it as a `static` field in the class, taking care to `synchronize` on its monitor to help achieve thread safety.

Note also that `test` will remain `false` once it evaluates to `false`.